# USB HD Freezes Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, freeze

I recently purchased a "Seagate STBX1000200 1TB Expansion 2.5 inch External Hard Drive". It has been working without problems until recently. When i plug the device into a USB port the device is recognised as it appears in the device manager but when i go to Windows Explorer and try to open it (or right click on it) it hangs/freezes windows explorer.

Please note i am using Windows 7 Professional. I have already tried various things without success after searching for people with similar problems. I did read that it could be a problem with how the computer assigns a drive letter. But when i go to disk management (when running as an administrator) it hangs and displays the following message:

> Connecting to virtual disk service

I'd appreciate it if anyone could offer some advice. Thanks

Comment: Does Disk Management only hang with the USB drive is plugged in?

Comment: @vCole: Yes only hangs when the USB stick is in.

Comment: I would try using a boot cd, like Ultimate Boot CD or Seagate's SeaTools to scan the USB drive for bad sectors/errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been having a similar problem: Windows was freezing for up to 4 mins when I plugged in a flash drive. At first I thought it was scanning or compressing it, but I also found a default in Defrag which required it to defrag all discs when plugged in. I turned that off!!

Finally I did a performance report (Action Centre) and found from a fault report I was still running Java v7, current is v10. I installed v10, rebooted, and all seems good for now. Flash drives open immediately.

I still have a problem with autoplay and file associations - when I go to Default Programs (Start button) and I try to open "Associate file types with programs", Windows Explorer freezes, then forces a restart. So I can't change file associations.